# iPhone X - Face ID - Unwanted "Enter your Password" text

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x, face-id

Since I got my iPhone X, I've been updating my app to work with Face ID. When Face ID fails too many times I get the text "Face Not Recognized" "Enter your Password". The problem I have is that for this prompt I don't want a fallback action so asking to enter a password doesn't make sense. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I'm using:

```
let context = LAContext()
context.localizedFallbackTitle = ""
context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
                       localizedReason: "Reason for bio auth",
                       reply: { (isSuccess, error) in
                            
                            
})
```

This is the result:

[image: Face id failure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in the upcoming iOS 11.2 release.